# Define IOS Logs From C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, c-preprocessor

How do I define Apple's NSLOG prints from C code ?
For Android it would be

```
#if _ANDROID__
#   include <android/log.h>
#   define LOGFUNC(level, fmt, args) __android_log_vprint(level, "andorid", fmt, args)
```

but How to to do it with Apple and NSLOG ?

I know I can do something like

```
#elif __APPLE__
#    define LOGFUNC(level, fmt, args) vprintf(fmt, args)
```

but I dont see the logs in the device Logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a C-stub implemented as Objective-C and compile that for OSX/iOS only, providing equivalents for Android, Windows, etc.  That's what I normally do when writing cross-platform code.

Log.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void logMsg(const char *fmt, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

AppleLog.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Log.h"

void logMsg(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@(fmt) arguments:va];
    va_end(va);

    NSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

You can also provide platform-specific code for `getHomeDirectory()`, `getTempDirectory()`, etc. in much the same way.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for app extension where I just found out I cant use Foundation, any idea what to do? (and anyway this is the correct answer for the question I asked)

Comment: @Roee84 Ah I guess you'll have to use `fprintf(stderr, ...);`.